# Axios request returns wrong value even with promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

I am trying to make an axios request but still receiving the wrong return value.

The axios method in on one file:

```
    export const sendFormSuccessfully = data => {
    let error = '';
   axios.post('example url', {data})
        .then(() => {
          error = '';
        })
        .catch(reason => {
           error = reason;
        });
      return error;
    };
```

I am calling the method from a different file:

```
 submittedForm = data => {
    const resultSubmission = sendFormSuccessfully(data);
    console.log(resultSubmission);
  };
```

But everytime I receive an empty string. I understand it is because it is async function but I thought that because axios returns promises the value should be correct.

Comment: you are right about async part, try using 
submittedForm = async (data) => {
    const resultSubmission = await sendFormSuccessfully(data);

Comment: I am getting error: Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined.

Comment: your return statement fires before the `then`/`catch` execute. You can use `async`/`await` as suggested (but you have to add the await, or return the promise and resolve it from within the  `then`/`catch` section.